# case statement in where clause depending on variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Depending on variable value my `Where` condition should change

If `@CustID <> 0` Then

```
Where SomeColumn = @BillID
```

Else

```
Where SomeColumn In (@BillID,0)
```

My Query:

```
Select * 
From SomeTable
Where SomeColumn = (Case When @CustID <> 0 Then @BillID Else /* What to Write Here */ End)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable ST
WHERE (@CustID <> 0 AND ST.SomeColumn = @BillID)
    OR (@CustID = 0 AND ST.SomeColumn IN (@BillID, 0))
```

Hope this will help.